# No matter what I do, my environment can't see libjpeg for Pillow on OSX 10.10 with Virtualenv

Tags: django, macos, virtualenv, python-imaging-library, homebrew

I've been researching this for hours. I can't seem to get it to work.

The issues is that I'm on OSX10.10, running Python 3.3. Everything worked great on 10.9.

I'm not even sure how to test it. I've done just about every step that has been suggested. Making new symlinks, linking and unlinking with Homebrew. Doing a custom install.

I'm just stuck. Anyone been able to sort this out?

In summary, I've uninstalled Pillow (and therefore PIL) and then installed the libjpeg files. Then I reinstalled Pillow with PIP.

Comment: Should be unrelated to the virtualenv. What did you install exactly? I don't know much of OSX, but on Linux distros, you'll usually have, for every library, a runtime package and a development package. You need both to install Pillow, as it compiles some adapter against the local lib.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is that the gist for Homebrew install Python 3.3 isn't working right. When I upgraded to Python 3.4 everything worked fine.

Recommend looking at this gist to revise and see what can be done to address this if you need 3.3

https://gist.github.com/dnozay/231a037d53e14052ccd6